# Extending arrows in R lattice

Tags: r, lattice

So I got this dummy code:

```
require(latticeExtra)
x<- 1:19
y<- 19:1
zeros <- (1:19)*0
plt <- xyplot(x~y)
plt <- plt + layer(panel.arrows(zeros,zeros,x,y,length=.1,col=1:19))
plt
```

Which produces the image below. I am looking for a way to extend or shorten the arrows away from the points they are drawn to. I believe this can be done using a base package, but I am curious if there is any way to do it in lattice.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to be more specific as to what you want. All you need to do to change the length of the arrows is to alter your `x` and `y` vectors using some basic geometry.

Comment: True, I could replace the x and y values with something else. I was just hoping there would be a way to extend the ling outward more, so in my real data I could exaggerate the line if the point is too close to the origin and I cannot see what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a multiplyer:

```
x <- 1:19
y <- 19:1
zeros <- (1:19)*0
plot(y~x)
arrows(x0=zeros,y0=zeros,x1=x*2,y1=y*2,col=1:19)
```

[image]

Comment: Ya, this is what I ended up doing essentially, only in the lattice equivalent. What is the easiest/prettiest way to label each arrow/line?